# How to insert data inside @ManyToMany relationship with extra field in join table in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I have two entities, Product and Attribute. I must to create a Many To Many relationship between Product Attribute, using another separate entity called ProductAttribute which should have a value field.
I can succesfully add and delete Products and Attributes to the database, but i cannot create any entry in ProductAttribute table since in the service class ( last code snippet ) the repository see's my new ProductAttribute as null.
Here are my Entities:

```
@Table
@Entity
@Data
public class Product{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    private List<ProductAttribute> productAttributes;
  // other fields -------
```

```
@Table
@Entity
@Data
public class Attribute{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id",nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "attribute")
    private List<ProductAttribute> productAttributes;
}
```

ProductAttribute entity and the Key class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_attribute")
@Data
public class ProductAttribute {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ProductAttributeKey id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("productId")
    private  Product product;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("attributeId")
    private Attribute attribute;

    @Column
    String value;
}
```

```
@Embeddable                                                     
@Data                                                           
@AllArgsConstructor                                             
@NoArgsConstructor                                              
public class ProductAttributeKey implements Serializable {      
    @Column(name = "product_id")                                
    private Long productId;                                     
                                                                
    @Column(name = "attribute_id")                              
    private Long attributeId;                                   
}
```

I implemented the JpaRepository for every Relationship except for ProductAttributeKey.
This is the method from the ProductAttributeService class:

```
@Transactional
    public ProductAttribute createProductAttribute(CreateProductAttributeModel createProductAttributeModel) {
        Product product = productRepository.findById(createProductAttributeModel.getProductId())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Product with id " + createProductAttributeModel.getProductId() + " not found!"));
        Attribute attribute = attributeRepository.findById(createProductAttributeModel.getAttributeId())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Attribute with id " + createProductAttributeModel.getAttributeId() + " not found!"));
        String value = createProductAttributeModel.getValue();

//create new productAttribute
        ProductAttribute productAttribute = new ProductAttribute();

        productAttribute.setProduct(product);
        productAttribute.setAttribute(attribute);
        productAttribute.setValue(value);


     return productAttributeRepository.save(productAttribute);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to save this `ProductAttribute` object using the `productAttributeRepository`, the repository is trying to generate an ID for the object, but since the id property is null, it fails to do so and returns a null object.

This should fix your Problem:

```
//create new productAttribute
ProductAttribute productAttribute = new ProductAttribute();

ProductAttributeKey id = new ProductAttributeKey();
id.setProductId(createProductAttributeModel.getProductId());
id.setAttributeId(createProductAttributeModel.getAttributeId());

productAttribute.setId(id);
productAttribute.setProduct(product);
productAttribute.setAttribute(attribute);
productAttribute.setValue(value);

return productAttributeRepository.save(productAttribute);
```

Comment: Thank you. I assumed that the Embeddable and EmbeddedId + MapsId annotations  would take care of the Id creation.